# I keep getting an error when I try to import tkFileDialog

Tags: python, tkinter

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Create-a-Simple-Python-Text-Editor/) to create my own simple text editor. However, I am coming across an error I don't know how to fix. I'm running this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.tkFileDialog
```

I've also tried this:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.tkFileDialog
```

Both of them give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter.tkFileDialog
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter.tkFileDialog'
```

I'm doing exactly what the tutorial said to do, but it won't work. Why is this happening?

For reference, I am using python 3.7 64-bit on windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3 tkinter does not have a tkFileDialog import. Instead you want to import `filedialog` like this.

```
import tkinter as tk # this is the preferred import for tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
x = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(x)
root.mainloop()
```

If you would prefer to only import the dialog's you specifically need you can do something like this.

```
import tkinter as tk # this is the preferred import for tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = tk.Tk()
x = askopenfilename()
print(x)
root.mainloop()
```

Update: Based on what Bryan has mentioned in the below here is another example that includes a delay to help prevent the issue mentioned. Though this only applies to dilogs opened before the mainloop has been reached and for many applications I would think this is not an issue as dialog is not often the first thing you have up in a GUI. However it is still good information to have.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

def print_file_name():
    x = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print(x)

root.after(100, print_file_name)
root.mainloop()
```

Or:

```
import tkinter as tk # this is the preferred import for tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = tk.Tk()

def print_file_name():
    x = askopenfilename()
    print(x)

root.after(100, print_file_name)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @BryanOakley I was just getting my answer up quickly. Was still working on the complete edit.

Comment: There's a known problem on windows about opening dialogs before `mainloop` is started. You should use `after` to open the dialog after mainloop has had a chance to  spin up.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh. I think I have run into that before. On a question some weeks ago. Do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: The original bug was reported against tk rather than tkinter. Here it is: https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=220431ffff It may have been fixed by now, I'm not really sure. It may not be an issue for python 3, but may still be a problem for 2.x.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks I will keep that in mind for future post.